# Limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = -2, \text{ and }  \lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = 0$$
Why
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \nexists.$$

Comment: Do you think it should exist? If so, what should the value of the limit be?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelAlbanese, I thought it could be $-\infty$..?

Comment: It depends on the context, but usually when people write $\lim\limits_{x\to a}h(x) = -\infty$, they mean that the limit doesn't exist, but decreases without bound. That is, it is used to denote a particular type of limit which does not exist (as opposed to a limit like $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=c$. Then 
$$-2=\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to2}g(x) = c\cdot 0=0 $$

Comment: er... how about $\infty$...?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: If I'm not mistaken, for this to work you need to assume that $g$ is non-zero in a deleted neighbourhood of $2$ so that the quotient function is defined and could *a priori* have a limit.